# Create New Variable Using Ifelse Contains Text

Tags: r, if-statement, text, dplyr

I want to create a new variable that indicates whether someone's diagnosis contained the words "Adolescent idiopathic scoliosis". There is additional text in the diagnoses as well. I want to create a variable that indicates whether someone has this diagnosis or not.

I originally wanted to do this using mutate in `dplyr`. Then I also tried `grepl`.

### grepl

```
Scoliosis$Adolesc.Idiopathic.Scoliosis <- 
  ifelse(grepl("Adoloescent idiopathic scoliosis",
        Scoliosis$Encounter.Primary.Visit.Diagnosis.Name),
  "Adolescent Idiopathic Scoliosis", "Different Diagnosis")
```

Also, could something like this work in `dplyr`? I didn't finish the code because every way I tried it failed:

```
Scoliosis <- Scoliosis %>% 
  mutate(Adolesc.Idiopathic.Scoliosis = ifelse(Encounter.Primary.Visit.Diagnosis.Name %in%
```

This is the table I get for the code:

```
 table(Scoliosis$Adolesc.Idiopathic.Scoliosis)
```

Different Diagnosis 
              75311

There should be some that come up with the result "Adolescent Idiopathic Scoliosis"

Comment: Have you tried something like `Scoliosis <- Scoliosis %>% 
  mutate(Adolesc.Idiopathic.Scoliosis = Encounter.Primary.Visit.Diagnosis.Name %in% "Adoloescent idiopathic scoliosic")`

Comment: your code looks like it might have a typo in it: "Adoloescent" where you meant to type "Adolescent" ?  Can we have a [mcve] please?  `%in%` will not work at all for this application ...

Comment: I'd probably use `tolower` to create a version with consistent case to compare to. Data can be messy...

Comment: Why not just make it a boolean column? Scoliosis$Adolesc.Idiopathic.Scoliosis <- 
grepl("Adoloescent idiopathic scoliosis",       Scoliosis$Encounter.Primary.Visit.Diagnosis.Name, ignore.case=T)

Comment: Thank you. I fixed the typo, changed it all to lower case to clean it up. Silly mistake on my part. I had been looking at it forever and just missed it. Appreciate the extra sets of eyes.